# How to install app from Google Play from our app?

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing an application which has some pdf files in its assets folder. It shows error message if the user don't have pdf reader installed on his device. Catching the error, I'm doing this:

```
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(Documents.this, "NO Pdf Viewer available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=en"));
    Documents.this.startActivity(i);
}
```

But this is giving just the webview of the app, from which the user can't download the Adobe Reader.
My question is, how to get the URL of the Adobe reader from which the user can download the app?
I want to redirect the user to Adobe reader app present in device's google play.
Please help me out on this.

Comment: I think normaly the device ask to show it in 'browser' or 'play stroe'. Did you maybe save 'always show in browser' on your device?

Comment: You can take help of [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-engaged-users-to-rate-your-app-in-the-android-market-appirater) post, just mold as per your requirements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
i.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=en"));
```

to

```
i.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=en"));
```